# How do I solve the problem of Provisioning Profile on MAC and flutter app

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I am new to IOS development in flutter and I have been struggling with uploading my project to App store for a while now. I get this error message

> There are no devices registered in your account on the developer website. Select a device run destination to have Xcode register it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You need to provide more details. How are you uploading your App ? from what I can guess, you have to register a device. For that, Run your Xcode project and select a device and run your app on it. Xcode will ask to register this device in the Developer portal. tap yes.